# how to get running process information in java?

Tags: java, linux, windows, process, environment

i want to get infomation about other running processes in my os.
(two things, process 'name' and 'path'.)

now, i'm using linux command like a "ps command".

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps x")
```

but because i want to run this in windows too, i'm searching other function can be works in windows and linux.

there are any java class or function have not os dependency?

Answer (score 1):

The updated Process API in Java 9 through [JEP 102](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/102) will help you if you're willing to upgrade early... This provides platform agnostic access to process trees...

See [ProcessHandle.allProcesses()](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#allProcesses--)

Example

```
ProcessHandle.allProcesses().forEach(processHandle -> 
    System.out.println("PID: " + processHandle.getPid() + 
    ", command: " + processHandle.info().command().orElse("Unknown")));
```

Comment: Really thanks, but it seems like not yet used  normally. There are any similar things can be used under the Java 8? Or, is it possible that configure my java file to use the java 9 if i insert java 9 file in the project directory? i'm sorry for poor english skill.